# Identifying an authenticated user in back-end page requested via window.open

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4, access-token, abp

We use **IdentityServer4** in our .NET solution, which also includes *AspNetCore* *Web API* and *Angular* front-end app.

There are standard middleware settings to setup identity like `app.UseAuthentication()` / `app.UseAuthorization()` / etc. (it's actually an **ABP** framework-based solution). As a result of these settings, all authentication tokens (**access_token**, **refresh_token**, etc.) are stored in *Local Storage* (I have not found where exactly I can select between *Local Storage* and other kinds, BTW).

Anyway, it has worked somehow in our DEV environment.

But suddenly the need to use `window.open` from *Angular* app popped up. This page is a Hangfire dashboard. Which accesses other resources related to dashboard functionality. And it caused a lot of headache: now, to identify user in server page called from `window.open` we need to use *cookies* (*URL* is not considered of course).

1. does it mean we have to switch fully from *Local Storage* to *Cookies* for storing tokens?
2. how and where to set it up? Or, if it's not too wild and senseless to just copy existing **access_token** to *Cookies* - when and where to do that? My idea was to copy **access_token** when it is created in *Local Storage* to *Cookies* and delete when a user logs off and probably under bunch of different conditions, like browser window is closed, etc. (which ones exactly?)
3. probably to set **refresh_token** to be stored in Cookies and read it in the mentioned server page, then obtain **access_token** by it (if it makes sense at all)

UPDATE: i've finally came up with the following, but it does not work. The idea is: when Angular app makes request to back-end and authentication token is already present - the token needs to be saved to cookies. I see the cookies is added. But later on - on next request - it falls into the condition again, because actually the given cookie is not saved:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
   OnTokenValidated = context =>
   {
       if (context.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken accessToken && !context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(accessTokenCookieName))
       {
           context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
               accessTokenCookieName,
               accessToken.RawData,
               new CookieOptions
               {
                   Domain = context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host,
                   Path = "/",
                   HttpOnly = true,
                   SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                   Secure = true,
                   MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
               });
       }
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   },
   ...
}
```

All apps are web application sharing the same domain. And CORS is set up. `AllowCredentials()` is called as well when setting up middleware.

Comment: Storing the access token in the cookie is not the best idea since you will then need to invent your own authentication scheme in order for this to work. Is that dashboard a server-side page that requires authentication upon being served, or wouldn’t it be enough to require authentication only when accessing the resources again via JavaScript. Then you could just read out the access token from local storage within your dashboard.

Comment: @poke this dashboard includes mainly server-side-built pages with special attribute working with HttpContext. So in the context I need to determine if Identity is authenticated. Current temporary solution supposes I will need to use Cookies as the only suitable resort. JS and CSS are just static resources to be available in Razor pages, they do not play any role in authentication process...

Comment: Then you should set up the normal cookie authentication scheme. Where are your access tokens being created? Are you using an external authentication provider, or is this in-app?

Comment: @poke we use ABP framework module for authentication, which is built on IdentityServer4: at the very end, all parts of our system are IIS web apps and resides on the same domain (including IdentityServer itself) and are authenticated via IdentityServer login form. As I mentioned, all tokens are now stored in Local Storage and I don't have idea what middleware setting is responsible for that. Now there no obvious mentioning "to use local storage".. So I don't know where to change it. `context.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer`.

Comment: Local storage is local to the client (the user’s browser), so it has nothing to do with the server configuration and you have no way to access it from the server. It is likely stored by whatever framework you use for the authentication in Angular. – The IdentityServer instance does not run in the *same* application as your web app/API, does it? It will be difficult to enable cookie based authentication as well there without changing your whole authentication setup… What you could do is have a separate authentication flow (using OpenID Connect) just for the dashboard.

Comment: @poke ah, i know that a local storage is a browser storage and not accessible on server, but i thought JWT-based authentication can easily select between storing tokens in 'local storage' (i.e. tokens can be read from headers only on server) and 'cookie' (tokens can be read from headers and cookies, if needed). But from your words I understand it's more complex and `AddJwtBearer` supposes using NO cookies (but local storage). If i want to use Cookies instead - I need to abandon `AddJwtBearer` and use `AddCookie` or something (?).

Comment: @poke And yes, IdentityServer is different app - so if I get rid of Local storage, I will break existing authentication from Angular as I understand or at least make my life much harder implementing something that already works out of the box for existing authentication scheme. BTW, if I set acess_token in cookies (taking from headers, for instance) and reuse it for dashboard - it works OK. We would like to receive current user identity and do not authenticate him twice, so separate authentication scheme is not a very attractrive idea to us...

Comment: JWT bearer uses a bearer token as part of the Authorization HTTP header. That bearer token is an access token. Cookie authentication uses a persisted user identity inside the cookie. This is *not* an access token and the two authentication schemes are not compatible out of the box.

Comment: @poke OK, thank you. So far I will store existing access_token in the protected cookies to identify user in dashboard page. And maybe will come up with the better idea later on.

Comment: RE your edit: Browsers don’t save cookies for AJAX requests.

Comment: @poke I see, thank you again. But I guess there needs to be the way to save them? For instance, when I do redirect to IdentityServer and login at its form, it's a pure form post, right? So I can save cookie there, right after access token creation... It's sad to think that I'm wrong and there is no way to make this Dashboard page work without sending token in URL or make user authenticate twice..